# Can I say "the colors are ranging from green to red"?

Tags: tense, present-continuous

I had to describe a map and I said :

> The map is a Mercator projection of the world, the countries colors
> **are ranging** from green (for lower "usage") to red (for higher
> "usage").

My teacher didn't think it was correct but I searched for this way of telling it and I did found examples where this form was used in what seems to be very similar contexts to the one of my sentence, for example :

> Yields are ranging from 0 to 40 acres.

Do the examples I found apply to my sentence, or is my teacher correct that "are ranging" isn't the right way to phrase it?

Comment: Simple present is idiomatic.  The colors *range* from....

Comment: What do you mean by "is idiomatic" ?

Comment: Look up the word *idiomatic* and you'll know. It's easy to find.

Comment: Ok... but does it mean that my formulation was incorrect?

Comment: @Trevor, it means a native speaker of English would phrase it without the "*are*" and would find if a native speaker read (or heard) your sentences, they would find the "*are*" odd and out of place and would probably balk at it. In short: omit the *are*.

Comment: It means your formulation is unidiomatic.  Correct is for math.

Comment: Regardless of whether you say "are ranging from" or "range from", saying "*from* green *to* red" doesn't make sense to me because it isn't at all clear what colours come in between green and red. On a colour wheel, green and red are on opposite sides, so the colours between them could be the oranges and yellows or could be the blues and purples depending on which way around the wheel you go.

Answer (score 6):

Because the map is static and the meaning of the colors will remain as they are currently, I would use the simple present:

> The map is a Mercator projection of the world. The countries' colors range from green (for lower "usage") to red (for higher "usage").

Without more context, the example you found sounds like it is describing yields that change from year to year (or month to month), and that they are currently within the range of 0 to 40 acres.

> The yields are ranging from 0 to 40 acres.

If we looked at a different time period, the range of the yields might be different, so using the present continuous shows that we are talking about what is happening in the current time period.

If we were talking about a dynamic graphic, we could use "are ranging".

> The colors are ranging from orange to red on the weather map indicating severe weather in the region. Just an hour ago, the colors ranged from green to blue so this is a dramatic change.

Answer (score 1):

For "are ranging" to make sense, two things should be true.  The verb ought to be dynamic.  The verb ought to be a main verb of some clause.

Colleen V already addressed the question of the stative vs. the dynamic sense of the verb in question.

In the original version of your sentence, only a comma separates the clause "the map is a Mercator projection of the world" from the rest of the sentence.  The form "are ranging" would be a complete verb (also called a finite verb) taking "the countries' colors" as its subject.  If that's the case, then you have a comma splice.  This is the reason Coleen punctuated her version as separate sentences.  The "range" in her sentence is also a finite verb.

If the comma is correct, then the phrase that follows cannot be an independent clause.  The phrase "the countries' colors ranging from green to red", with no "are" in sight, is an absolute phrase which can attach to the main clause with nothing more than a comma.  Unlike the finite form "are ranging", the participle "ranging" works for either the stative or the dynamic sense of the verb.

There are more than one way to correct this sentence.  Different ways have different results.  Without knowing more about your intentions, I don't know what corrections to recommend.

Comment: I'm glad someone explained the punctuation issue. Using a comma to connect _The map is a projection, the colors ranging..._ is something I know is grammatically OK but didn't know how to explain clearly. I choose to rephrase the sentence in a way that I thought would be clear to a learner, but given the lack of context, I agree that there is more than one way to rephrase it.